# How to iterate over pairs in a column in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, reduce

I have a data frame like this, imported from a parquet file:

```
| Store_id | Date_d_id  | 
|    0     | 23-07-2017 |  
|    0     | 26-07-2017 |   
|    0     | 01-08-2017 |   
|    0     | 25-08-2017 |  
|    1     | 01-01-2016 |  
|    1     | 04-01-2016 |   
|    1     | 10-01-2016 |
```

What I am trying to achieve next is to loop through each customer's date in pair and get the day difference. Here is what it should look like:

```
| Store_id | Date_d_id  | Day_diff |
|    0     | 23-07-2017 |   null   |
|    0     | 26-07-2017 |    3     |
|    0     | 01-08-2017 |    6     |   
|    0     | 25-08-2017 |    24    |  
|    1     | 01-01-2016 |    null  |  
|    1     | 04-01-2016 |    3     |   
|    1     | 10-01-2016 |    6     |
```

And finally, I will like to reduce the data frame to the average day difference by customer:

```
| Store_id | avg_diff |
|    0     | 7.75     |  
|    1     |  3       |
```

I am very new to Scala and I don't even know where to start. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Also, I am using Zeppelin notebook

Comment: Can you post some code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `lag(Date) over Window partition` and a UDF to calculate the difference in days between consecutive rows, then follow by grouping the DataFrame for the average difference in days.  Note that `Date_d_id` is converted to `yyyy-mm-dd` format for proper String ordering within the Window partitions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  (0, "23-07-2017"),
  (0, "26-07-2017"),
  (0, "01-08-2017"),
  (0, "25-08-2017"),
  (1, "01-01-2016"),
  (1, "04-01-2016"),
  (1, "10-01-2016")
).toDF("Store_id", "Date_d_id")

def daysDiff = udf(
  (d1: String, d2: String) => {
    import java.time.LocalDate 
    import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS

    DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(d1), LocalDate.parse(d2))
  }
)

val df2 = df.
  withColumn( "Date_ymd",
    regexp_replace($"Date_d_id", """(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)""", "$3-$2-$1")).
  withColumn( "Prior_date_ymd",
    lag("Date_ymd", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("Store_id").orderBy("Date_ymd"))).
  withColumn( "Days_diff",
    when($"Prior_date_ymd".isNotNull, daysDiff($"Prior_date_ymd", $"Date_ymd")).
    otherwise(0L))

df2.show
// +--------+----------+----------+--------------+---------+
// |Store_id| Date_d_id|  Date_ymd|Prior_date_ymd|Days_diff|
// +--------+----------+----------+--------------+---------+
// |       1|01-01-2016|2016-01-01|          null|        0|
// |       1|04-01-2016|2016-01-04|    2016-01-01|        3|
// |       1|10-01-2016|2016-01-10|    2016-01-04|        6|
// |       0|23-07-2017|2017-07-23|          null|        0|
// |       0|26-07-2017|2017-07-26|    2017-07-23|        3|
// |       0|01-08-2017|2017-08-01|    2017-07-26|        6|
// |       0|25-08-2017|2017-08-25|    2017-08-01|       24|
// +--------+----------+----------+--------------+---------+

val resultDF = df2.groupBy("Store_id").agg(avg("Days_diff").as("Avg_diff"))

resultDF.show
// +--------+--------+
// |Store_id|Avg_diff|
// +--------+--------+
// |       1|     3.0|
// |       0|    8.25|
// +--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` function to get the previous date over `Window` function, then do some manipulation to get the final `dataframe` that you require

first of all the `Date_d_id` column need to be converted to include timestamp for sorting to work correctly

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val timestapeddf = df.withColumn("Date_d_id", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"Date_d_id", "dd-MM-yyyy")))
```

which should give your `dataframe` as

```
+--------+-------------------+
|Store_id|          Date_d_id|
+--------+-------------------+
|       0|2017-07-23 00:00:00|
|       0|2017-07-26 00:00:00|
|       0|2017-08-01 00:00:00|
|       0|2017-08-25 00:00:00|
|       1|2016-01-01 00:00:00|
|       1|2016-01-04 00:00:00|
|       1|2016-01-10 00:00:00|
+--------+-------------------+
```

then you can apply the `lag` function over `window` function and finally get the date difference as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Store_id").orderBy("Date_d_id")
val laggeddf = timestapeddf.withColumn("Day_diff", when(lag("Date_d_id", 1).over(windowSpec).isNull, null).otherwise(datediff($"Date_d_id", lag("Date_d_id", 1).over(windowSpec))))
```

`laggeddf` should be

```
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|Store_id|Date_d_id          |Day_diff|
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|0       |2017-07-23 00:00:00|null    |
|0       |2017-07-26 00:00:00|3       |
|0       |2017-08-01 00:00:00|6       |
|0       |2017-08-25 00:00:00|24      |
|1       |2016-01-01 00:00:00|null    |
|1       |2016-01-04 00:00:00|3       |
|1       |2016-01-10 00:00:00|6       |
+--------+-------------------+--------+
```

now the final step is to use `groupBy` and `aggregation` to find the average

```
laggeddf.groupBy("Store_id")
  .agg(avg("Day_diff").as("avg_diff"))
```

which should give you

```
+--------+--------+
|Store_id|avg_diff|
+--------+--------+
|       0|    11.0|
|       1|     4.5|
+--------+--------+
```

Now if you want to neglect the null `Day_diff` then you can do

```
laggeddf.groupBy("Store_id")
          .agg((sum("Day_diff")/count($"Day_diff".isNotNull)).as("avg_diff"))
```

which should give you

```
+--------+--------+
|Store_id|avg_diff|
+--------+--------+
|       0|    8.25|
|       1|     3.0|
+--------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful